# Aptana 3.4.2 keeps closing on it's own

Tags: linux, ubuntu, aptana, linux-mint

I'm using linux mint 16 and Aptana studio 3.4.2.

Aptana keeps closing on me. I've updated my OS and tried updating Aptana and it keeps saying no updates.

Has anybody else had this problem? If so, how did you fix it?

Any help would be great thanx

Phil

Answer (score 0):

The fix is pretty simple: in the folder where you've extracted / install Aptana Studio 3, you should have a file called "AptanaStudio3.ini" - open this file with a text editor and at the end of the file, add this line:

-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla